# why ctr did not show the container

Tags: container

When I tried to use ctr to show the container like this:

```
# ctr images list
REF TYPE DIGEST SIZE PLATFORMS LABELS
```

The output is null, am I missing something? Is it possible to show the image list when using `ctr`? This is the `ctr` version info:

```
# ctr -v
ctr github.com/containerd/containerd v1.6.12
```

I have fetched many images into `containerd`. Actually the `containerd` was running for years. I have found that `crictl` can list the image but `ctr` cannot.

Why can `ctr` not show the container?